# Does the $k$th decimal position of a prime define a (simply) normal sequence?

Tags: number-theory

For a given integer $k \geq 1$, we construct a sequence $s_k:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1,...,9\}$ so that for each $n \geq 1$, $s_k(n)$ is equal to the $k$th digit of the decimal representation of the $n$th prime $p_n$, where we count digits starting from the right. For instance, if $k=2$, then $s_k(9)$ is the $2$nd digit of $23$, hence $s_k(9)=2$. If $p_n<10^{k-1}$, simply let $s_k(n) = 0$.

A reasonable sounding conjecture is that this behaves "randomly" for $k>1$, which leads me to my first question.

> Is it true that for every $k>1$, the real number $\alpha_k \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}0.s_k(1)s_k(2)s_k(3)...$ is normal in base $10$? Is it simply normal?

For $k=1$, this cannot be normal, since $s_1(n)$ is never even or $5$ for large $n$. However, we can say something else.

> Fix a bijection $g:\{1,3,7,9\} \to \{0,1,2,3\}$ and consider the sequence $b_n$ defined so that $b_n$ is the rightmost digit of the $(n+4)$th prime. By the Chebotarev's density theorem, the real number $\beta \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} 0.g(b_1)g(b_2)g(b_3)...$ is *simply* normal in base $4$. Is it normal in the general sense?

It's $n+4$ above to avoid the primes $2$ and $5$, in which case the rightmost digit is not in $\{1,3,7,9\}$. The "$4$" in the $n+4$ isn't particularly related to the base $4$, to avoid confusion.

I thought of this question after having come across the [Erdos-Copeland constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant), a real number whose decimal representation is exactly the primes in base $10$ concatenated. This is known to be normal in base $10$. However, the normality of that does not seem to imply the claims I've described above, or at least I can't see how.

It's possible that this question is trivial, but I can't think of the solution. Finally, note while other similar questions of prime-digits have been asked, I haven't seen an exact duplicate of this yet.

Comment: I'm no expert in this field at all but maybe your question can be reduced to the known normality of certain numbers. If we could prove that any infinite subset of the digits of a normal number generated by a rule which uses only the position of the digit (not its value) and takes each position only once forms a normal number, then you could deduce the normality of your sequence from that of the Copeland-Erdös constant. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: +1 A simple first frequency statistics ($\mu$, $\sigma$) supports an affirmative answer.

Comment: This is essentially the question studied in Lemke Oliver and Sound’s recent and well-publicized paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03720.pdf.  I believe very little is known in terms of proving normality beyond blocks of length 1 (in most cases we don’t even know that all blocks of length 2 occur infinitely often, let alone equally).  But conjecturally we expect it to be the case; the paper tries to explain heuristically why it empirically takes a looooot of samples for the distribution to look uniform.